# Definition of the field $F(\alpha)$

Tags: field-theory

I have a little doubt. Let $F$ field and $\alpha\not\in F$. Then $F(\alpha):=\left\{a+b\alpha:a,b\in F\right\}$ by definition? or is it possible to prove it?

Comment: Consider $F=\mathbb Q$ and $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2$

Comment: or $\alpha=\pi$

Comment: I get it. I think the correct definition should be
$F(\alpha)=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i\alpha^i: n\in\mathbb{N},a_i\in\mathbb{F} \right\}$
right?

Comment: @eraldcoil This is the case when $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$. In general you should also add in quotients of elements of that form.

Comment: is that part of a theorem?

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly asking for what is a simple extension.

So better to refer to its definition, like in [Wikipedia  simple extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension?wprov=sfti1).